# How to dial extension for participants in conference on twilio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, twilio-api

I have a scenario in which adding participants in a conference call. I am doing like that

```
conference_name = "demo"
  account_sid = "xyz"
  auth_token = "xyz"

  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

  company_number_participent1 = client.conferences(conference_name).participants.create(from: 'xyz', to: "xyz")
  customer_number_participent2 = client.conferences(conference_name).participants.create(from: 'xyz', to: 'xyz')
```

and it works exactly. Now I want to add dial an extension also once participant added in call. As per twilio documentation for normall call we can add a parameter `,send_digits: '12#` for an extension. When I do like that it gives an error.

```
company_number_participent = client.conferences(conference_name).participants.create(from: 'xyz', to: "xyz",send_digits: '1')
```

How I can dial extension for conference participant in twilio?

Comment: Did you end up finding a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see sendDigits as a parameter for the create participant request. Instead use the [calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource) to place the call and [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) to handle sending digits and adding the participant to the conference.

Comment: thank you for answer... Do you think its possible to add call resource as participant?